# Proofs of VC theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, numerical-methods

I am collecting VC-theorem's proofs

I've found three distinct proofs of VC-theorem ( also called Saur-Shelah lemma or shatter function lemma )
http://www.cse.buffalo.edu/~hungngo/classes/2010/711/lectures/sauer.pdf

here is the theorem:

> [image] "Lectures on discrete geometry
>   Jiri Matousek"

**Does any one know another proof??**

Answer (score 1):

It is an old question... for the record, the shortest proof I know goes via a lemma of Alain Pajor.

[Gil Kalai](https://gilkalai.wordpress.com/2008/09/28/extremal-combinatorics-iii-some-basic-theorems/) credits Noga Alon while [R. P. Anstee, Lajos Rónyai, and Attila Sali](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s003730200003) credit others.

P.S. I realize a proof is also in the Wikipedia article on [Sauer–Shelah lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sauer%E2%80%93Shelah_lemma).